# Why this function is triggered directly instead of by click in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a object declare like this:

```
function weapon ( id, name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.call; 
}
```

then I have created an instance of it:

```
someweapon = new weapon (1, 'gun');
someweapon.call = function() { //do something };
```

When I am creating a  element:

```
<img src='...' onclick='someweapon.call()' />
```

supposingly, I will see a clickable image which I can click it to invoke the function. However, the function (someweapon.call()) is called automatically as soon as the image is shown.

Any solution to this?

Comment: maybe the function is being called by other part of the code, is posible?

Answer (score 2):

I think it has something to do with the funcktion name: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call
So you might try a different one.

Answer (score 2):

For me your code works. The `.call()` method is probably getting called from somewhere else.

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/YYkH4/1/) is a snippet that works for me.

JavaScript:

```
function weapon ( id, name){
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
}

someweapon = new weapon (1, 'gun');
someweapon.call = function() { alert("called"); };
```

You don't need to `this.call` inside the `weapon()`. If you define it there it has still value `undefined`. You can also write `this.call = function() { alert("called"); };` inside `weapon()` which means it will be accessible by every instance of `weapon` and not only by `someweapon`.

HTML:

```
<img src='http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png' onclick='someweapon.call()' />
```

**EDIT**: *tom* and *Jared Farrish* have a good point. `call()` is already [defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) for functions. You are defining `.call()` for objects and not for functions so nothing should get (theoretically) overwritten, but it is a good practice to not use names like that as it may be confusing. Rename `.call()` to something else.

Comment: I removed the reference to overriding `.call()` while I looked into it a little more. I still think it's a bad idea, at least confusing, to do so. ([MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call))